# Grade report sentinal loop test in python

Tags: python

I could use some help solving an error. This is my code that takes in multiple inputs, and outputs ( the amount of inputs, the amount of students who miss the test, the students who got a grade higher then 80, the average of those who took the test, and the average of the entire class including those who missed.

```
#number of students who miss, and get a highscore
num_miss = 0
num_high = 0
total = 0
count = 0

#The minimum and maximum values
min_score = 100.00
max_score = 0.0

score = int(input("Enter a Score(-1 to quit):     "))
#The loop to test score inputs, and the students who missed or got a high score
while score >-1:
    if score >= 80:
        num_high += 1
    elif score == 0:
        num_miss += 1

    if score < min_score:
        min_score = score
    if score > max_score:
        max_score = score

    score = int(input("Enter a Score(-1 to quit):     "))
    # an incriment to count the total for average, and the amount of students that took the exam
    total += score
    count += 1
    students = count
#formulas for creating the averages
average = total / count
average2 = total / (count + -num_miss)

#prints grade report with a dashed line under it    
print("Grade Report")
print("-" * 38)

if count >= 0:
    print("Total number of students in the class:      {}".format(students))
    print("Number of students who missed the exam:     {}".format(num_miss))
    print("Number of students who took the exam:       {}".format(count - num_miss))
    print("Number of students who scored high:         {}".format(num_high))
    print("Average of all students in the class:       {0:.2f}".format(average))
    print("Average of students taking the exam:        {0:.2f}".format(average2))
```

This is the problem: by inputing all these values: 65, 98, 45, 76, 87, 94, 43, 0, 89, 80, 79, 0, 100, 55, 75, 0, 77, -1 to end

---

This is what my professor gets for an output

---

### Grade Report

```
 1. Total number of students in the class: 17 
 2.Number of students who missed the exam: 3
 3.Number of students who took the exam: 14 
 4.Numberof students who scored high: 6 
 5.Average of all students in the class:62.5 
 6.Average of students taking the exam: 75.9
```

This is what i get for an output

---

### Grade Report

```
1.Total number of students in the class:      17
2.Number of students who missed the exam:     3
3.Number of students who took the exam:       14
4.Number of students who scored high:         6
5.Average of all students in the class:       58.64
6.Average of all students taking the exam:    71.21
```

How do I fix my averages so that they are the same as my professors?

Comment: When you're asking for the input inside the while - make sure it's the last part of the while loop... That way... when you do the calculations it will be on the correct score for that iteration of the loop

Comment: Yes, you can tell from the division.

Comment: @John Clements Idk why that changes the calculations.But this did solve the problem. You should change this comment to an answer so I can give you a green check.

Comment: Just to note - you could use `for score in iter(lambda: int(input('Enter score:')), -1)` as the loop instead but I guess it's good to use a `while` for learning

Answer (score 1):

You're including the last "-1" as part of your data set.

Also, Why are you doing this:

```
average2=total/(count+-numMiss)
```

as opposed to this:

```
average2=total/(count-numMiss)
```

Comment: That is a typo from me trying to test stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you include the `-1`. You should do

```
while True:
    ...

    score=int(input("Enter a Score(-1 to quit):     "))

    if score == -1:
        break

    ...
```

Comment: i thought this might be the reason. But where would i implement this test. Because if i put while true: it will say true is not defined

Comment: You want `True` with a capital `T`. `true` is a variable, `True` is the constant always-true-value.

Comment: Oh okay, but yeah I have never used break before. but by putting score=int(input("Enter a Score(-1 to quit):     ")) at the end of the loop it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You only need this line once:

```
score = int(input("Enter a Score(-1 to quit):     "))
```

And it should be inside the loop.

The code should look something like this:

```
while True:
    score = int(input("Enter a Score(-1 to quit):     "))
    if score <= -1:
        break
```

Also, this line can move outside the loop:

```
students = count
```

Comment: is break a python function?